# Add repository to SLES 12.3 google cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sles

I've created SLES 12.3 SP3 google cloud instance, but it has no repositories available. When I run `zypper install ...` I get

> Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.

Should I choose openSUSE 12.3 repositories instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, no you cannot add the openSuse repositories to a SLES installation. Or better you can add the repositories but it won't work or give you headaches. Some packages might work, some not, some will have dependency issues...

For SLES you need subscription to add their online update repositories. You still could download the DVDs provided by SLES and use them as local repositories but that would exclude any updates and you definitely want to have updates.
So either get yourself a SLES subscription or reinstall with openSuse.

Comment: Thx, it's pretty sad. RHEL instances has repositories enabled, i supposed with SLES it would be the same(

Comment: But RHEL repositories are only really active if you have subscription.

Comment: Well, i can install all packages without any subscriptions with RHEL. "yum update" works fine, source repo is "rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms".

Comment: Well, then there is a subscription attached to the system. Not sure how that is handled with the google-cloud-platform or if it is only valid for 30-day evaluation.

Comment: "subscription-manager version" tells the system is not registered and "subscription-manager repos" tells "This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.".
Maybe it's an evaluation, should check that.

Comment: "yum update" still works, though it writes "This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register."